# how to track email which is sent using Gmail API

Tags: php, gmail-api

I want to track email if it is opened or not. Email should be sent using Gmail API. I have tried to send and image with the path of my php script which takes an ID of message and logs it. My email body content code looks like:

```
$strMailContent="image ->  <img border='2' src='http://localhost/app/mailTracker.php?id=12' alt='image for email'>  ";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . $charset . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= $strMailContent . "\r\n";
```

Of course my whole email message is compiled but this is the relevant part so i'm sharing only this. I have specified `'Content-Type: text/html;` then why it is not sending the image? only text appears on receiver side. Image does not appear at all. I tried inline method too. That didn't work either. Code for inline is:

```
$strMailContent="image ->  <img border='2' src='cid:trackerImage' alt='image for email'>  ";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . $charset . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= $strMailContent . "\r\n";

$strRawMessage .= "\r\n--{$aboundary}\r\n";

//construct inline images here
$fileName = "images/ajax-loader.gif";

$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: image/gif; name="'. $fileName .'";' . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Description: inline;' . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-ID: <'.'trackerImage'.'>' . "\r\n\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($trackerPath)), 76, "\n") . "\r\n";
```

Problem with inline approach is that image only appears on desktop client, not on web client. Another issue is that using inline approach, I cannot achieve my goal, which is to call my script and do logging stuff. Please anyone share thoughts or ideas on how can I do email tracking (check if it is opened or not yet) using Gmail API?